# Noticing a warning to limit scraped results with BeautifulSoup in Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape sales data from eBay with BeautifulSoup in Python for recently sold items and it works very well with the following code which finds all prices and all dates from sold items.

```
 price = []
   
    try:
        p = soup.find_all('span', class_='POSITIVE')

    except:
        p = 'nan'
          
    for x in p:
        x = str(x)
        x = x.replace(' ','"')
        x = x.split('"')
        
        if '>Sold' in x:
            continue
        else:
            price.append(x)
```

Now I am running into a problem though. As seen in the picture below for this URL (https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=p2334524.m570.l1313&_nkw=babe+ruth+1933+goudey+149+psa+%281.5%29&_sacat=0&LH_TitleDesc=0&_osacat=0&_odkw=babe+ruth+1933+goudey+149+psa+1.5&LH_Complete=1&rt=nc&LH_Sold=1), eBay sometimes suggests other search results if there are not enough for specific search queries. [Check out the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0dbs.png)

By that, my code not only finds the correct prices but also those of the suggested results below the warning. I was trying to find out where the warning message is located and delete every listing that is being found afterward, but I cannot figure it out. I also thought that I can search for the prices one by one but even then I cannot figure out how to notice when the warning appears.

Is there any other way you guys can think of to solve this?

I am aware that this is really specific

Comment: The expected output is just the prices? Or also the product details(like the name...)

Comment: Mainly interested in the prices and the dates (they are also being found by the find_all)

Answer (score 3):

You can scrape the number of results (Shown in picture) and make a loop with the range of the results.

[image: screenshot]

The code will be something like:

```
results = soup.find...
#You have to make the variable a int so replace everything extra
results = int(results)

  
for i in range(1, results):
        price[i] = str(price[i])
        price[i] = price[i].replace(' ','"')
        price[i] = price[i].split()
        
        if '>Sold' in price[i]:
            continue
        else:
```

Comment: Oh my god, you're right!! I even have the number of results stored previously in my code! Thanks buddy!